# Adobe Canvas HTML5 AS3 Click Tag

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash, html5-canvas

Have been using flash for some time but now there is a requirement to produce HTML 5 banners.

I have used Canvas to create my banner which is working as expected, however, I'm confused (as it seems most people are), as to how to add an AS3 clicktag that will work with Adwords and DoubleClick. Alternatively, can the clicktag be added to the HTML outputted file only?

Instructions that I've found online seem to be incredibly confusing as to where code is added, whether code is added on timeline or object, whether instance names are given, or whether code is added externally only.

My current Canvas project has no actionscript in it at all. The HTML outputted code I have modified based on findings now looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="ad.size" content="width=300,height=250">

<title>300x250-test3</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var clickTag = "http://www.google.com";
</script>

<script src="easeljs-0.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="tweenjs-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="movieclip-0.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="300x250-test3.js"></script>

<script>
var canvas, stage, exportRoot;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    exportRoot = new lib._300x250test3();

    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(exportRoot);
    stage.update();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="init();" style="background-color:#D4D4D4; margin:0; padding:0;">
<a href="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag)">
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="250" style="background-color:#FFFFFF"></canvas>
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

This appears to work and function as expected, that is, assuming that the Google URL added is for testing purposes only and the distributors will alter this to point to the correct URL.

The banners will ultimately be on either Adwords or Doubleclick.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than wrap your canvas in an <a> tag, consider handling this in JavaScript. Inside your `init` method, just add a "click" listener to your canvas (DOM events) or Stage (EaselJS events):

```
function init() {
    // Other code (not shown)

    // DOM event (directly on canvas)
    canvas.addEventListener("click", function() { 
        window.open(window.clickTag); 
    }, false);

    // OR
    // EaselJS events (on the EaselJS stage)
    stage.on("stagemouseup" ,function(event) {
        window.open(window.clickTag);
    });
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Have you tried and tested this Lanny with Adwords and Doubleclick and is this from experience?

Comment: I have not. I do not know how the actual tracking calls work, but this is how you would handle interaction with the content.

Comment: Thanks. Will let you know how i get on.

Answer (score 0):

Both DCM and AdWords use this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">var clickTag = "https://www.google.com";</script>
```

You get a cursor by default if you include a button symbol in your Flash Canvas document. I am using this in my published HTML file.

```
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="500" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; width:300px; height:250px" onclick="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag)"></canvas>
```

Authoring at 2X the size is for retina display. Supposedly AdWords has caved on allowing external links to anything other than Google fonts, but I won't believe it until I see someone report they didn't fail QA for using CDN hosted files, but for future reference, here are the Google hosted links.

https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/6307288